# Fetch возвращает [object Promise] вместо данных с response.text() и response.json()

Tags: javascript, fetch

Написал данный код:

```html
const fetch_url = ({URL, BODY, CONTENT_TYPE, RESPONSE_TYPE}, METHOD) => {
  CONTENT_TYPE = Number(CONTENT_TYPE);
  RESPONSE_TYPE = Number(RESPONSE_TYPE);
  let single = METHOD === 'GET' || METHOD === 'DELETE';
  return fetch(URL, {
    method: METHOD,
    headers: single ? {} : {'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? 'text/plain' : 'application/json'},
    redirect: single ? 'follow' : 'follow',
    body: CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? String(BODY) : JSON.stringify(BODY)})
  .then(res => {
    switch (RESPONSE_TYPE) {
      case 1:
        return res.text();
      case 2:
        return res.json();
      case 3:
        return String(res.ok);
      case 4:
        return res.status;
      case 5:
        return res.statusText;
      case 6:
        return res.type;
      case 7:
        return String(res.redirected);
      case 8:
        return res.url;
      case 9: default:
        return single ? res.url : String(res.bodyUsed);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => '');
};
```

Он должен служить оболочкой для использования Fetch пользователями. Сам код работал, но функционала не хватало. И я решил добавить возможность возвращать сразу несколько `res`

Получилось это:

```html
const fetch_url = ({URL, BODY, CONTENT_TYPE, RESPONSES_TYPES, SPLIT}, METHOD) => {
  SPLIT = String(SPLIT);
  CONTENT_TYPE = Number(CONTENT_TYPE);
  RESPONSES_TYPES = RESPONSES_TYPES.split(' ').filter(word => word !== '');
  let single = METHOD === 'GET' || METHOD === 'DELETE';
  return fetch(URL, {
    method: METHOD,
    headers: single ? {} : {'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? 'text/plain' : 'application/json'},
    redirect: single ? 'follow' : 'follow',
    body: CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? String(BODY) : JSON.stringify(BODY)})
  .then(res => {
    let responses = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= RESPONSES_TYPES.length - 1; i++) {
      switch (Number(RESPONSES_TYPES[i])) {
        case 1:
          responses += SPLIT + res.text(); break;
        case 2:
          responses += SPLIT + res.json(); break;
        case 3:
          responses += SPLIT + String(res.ok); break;
        case 4:
          responses += SPLIT + res.status; break;
        case 5:
          responses += SPLIT + res.statusText; break;
        case 6:
          responses += SPLIT + res.type; break;
        case 7:
          responses += SPLIT + String(res.redirected); break;
        case 8:
          responses += SPLIT + res.url; break;
        case 9: default:
          responses += SPLIT + single ? res.url : String(res.bodyUsed); break;
      }
    }
    return SPLIT === '' ? responses : responses.slice(1);
  })
  .catch(err => '');
};
```

Ну и как обычно происходит в таких ситуациях код перестал нормально работать. Вместо информации с `res.text()` и `res.json()` возвращается [object Promise]

(`res.status`, `res.type` и тд. при этом работают)

Может кто-нибудь сказать как это исправить?

Comment: Сделать фукнцию асинхронной **async** и дожидаться выполнения fetch запроса с помощью **await**

Comment: Впрочем эта асинхронная функция всё равно будет возвращать промис

Comment: Так `res.text()` и `res.json()` асинхронные. Т.ч. нужен еще один `.then()` - вот там и будут все данные.

Comment: @ksa А куда можно добавить `.then()`? Если добавлять перед основным, то код перестаёт работать, а добавить его в `case` нельзя...

Comment: `.then()`пойдет за уже существующем `.then()`. Тебе в первом придется сформировать массив с уже готовыми данными и промисами. Потом дать команду `return Promise.all(<этот_массив>)`. Второй `.then()` уже получит массив результатов - делай с ним что хочешь.

Comment: @ksa Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Т.е. тебе дважды придется крутить цикл в каждом `.then()` и `switch`-ить типы возвращаемых значений. Я могу оформить ответом то что тут описал но проверить работоспособность не смогу.

Comment: @ksa Буду благодарен если оформите

Comment: стоит обратить внимание, что ты не можешь у одного Response вызвать сначала `.text()` потом `.json()` или наоборот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нашей с ТСом переписке я ему предложил вот такую модель обработки его данных. Вот только на работоспособность мне проверить это не на чем.

```
const fetch_url = ({
  URL,
  BODY,
  CONTENT_TYPE,
  RESPONSES_TYPES,
  SPLIT
}, METHOD) => {
  SPLIT = String(SPLIT);
  CONTENT_TYPE = Number(CONTENT_TYPE);
  RESPONSES_TYPES = RESPONSES_TYPES.split(' ').filter(word => word !== '');
  let single = METHOD === 'GET' || METHOD === 'DELETE';
  return fetch(URL, {
      method: METHOD,
      headers: single ? {} : {
        'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? 'text/plain' : 'application/json'
      },
      redirect: single ? 'follow' : 'follow',
      body: CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? String(BODY) : JSON.stringify(BODY)
    })
    .then(res => {
      const responses = [];
      for (let i = 0; i <= RESPONSES_TYPES.length - 1; i++) {
        switch (Number(RESPONSES_TYPES[i])) {
          case 1:
            responses.push(res.text());
            break;
          case 2:
            responses.push(res.json());
            break;
          case 3:
            responses.push(String(res.ok));
            break;
          case 4:
            responses.push(res.status);
            break;
          case 5:
            responses.push(res.statusText);
            break;
          case 6:
            responses.push(res.type);
            break;
          case 7:
            responses.push(String(res.redirected));
            break;
          case 8:
            responses.push(res.url);
            break;
          case 9:
          default:
            responses.push(single ? res.url : String(res.bodyUsed));
            break;
        }
      }
      return Promise.all(responses);
    })
    .then(arr => {
      let responses = '';
      for (let i = 0; i <= RESPONSES_TYPES.length - 1; i++) {
        responses += SPLIT + arr[i];
      }
      return SPLIT === '' ? responses : responses.slice(1);
    })
    .catch(err => '');
};
```

Вот такой еще вариант можно сделать

```
const fetch_url = async({
  URL,
  BODY,
  CONTENT_TYPE,
  RESPONSES_TYPES,
  SPLIT
}, METHOD) => {
  SPLIT = String(SPLIT);
  CONTENT_TYPE = Number(CONTENT_TYPE);
  RESPONSES_TYPES = RESPONSES_TYPES.split(' ').filter(word => word !== '');
  let single = METHOD === 'GET' || METHOD === 'DELETE';
  try {
    let res = await fetch(URL, {
      method: METHOD,
      headers: single ? {} : {
        'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? 'text/plain' : 'application/json'
      },
      redirect: single ? 'follow' : 'follow',
      body: CONTENT_TYPE === 1 ? String(BODY) : JSON.stringify(BODY)
    })
    let responses = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <= RESPONSES_TYPES.length - 1; i++) {
      switch (Number(RESPONSES_TYPES[i])) {
        case 1:
          responses += SPLIT + await res.text();
          break;
        case 2:
          responses += SPLIT + await res.json();
          break;
        case 3:
          responses += SPLIT + String(res.ok);
          break;
        case 4:
          responses += SPLIT + res.status;
          break;
        case 5:
          responses += SPLIT + res.statusText;
          break;
        case 6:
          responses += SPLIT + res.type;
          break;
        case 7:
          responses += SPLIT + String(res.redirected);
          break;
        case 8:
          responses += SPLIT + res.url;
          break;
        case 9:
        default:
          responses += SPLIT + single ? res.url : String(res.bodyUsed);
          break;
      }
    }
    return SPLIT === '' ? responses : responses.slice(1);
  } catch (err) {
    return ''
  }
};
```

Comment: есть вероятность что такой подход не будет работать, потому что response может читать тело только один раз

Comment: Значит не получится задать 1 и 2 одновременно, вот и все.

Comment: @ksa Немного задержался, но сейчас проверил. Спасибо, оба варианта работают стабильно. Возвращать сразу несколько `res` нельзя, но это не критично, главное, что хотя бы один экземпляр работает. Единственное я столкнулся с одной странностью. (https://ipapi.co/json/) этот сайт возвращает ошибку в обоих вариантах, хотя чистый `get()` работает с ним.

Comment: @TrueFantøm, ну тут только тестить... Я показал некую иллюстрацию своего рассказа в переписке.

Comment: @ksa Ладно, спасибо ещё раз тогда.